# trigger scroll events on mobile momentum scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

Not sure if I worded it correctly, but I am almost done with a workaround for creating sticky elements on mobile. So element is in doc flow then sticks to the top once it hits top of window. Waypoints.js does this but does not work very well on mobile.

So far I have been able to get it working normally on desktop (not a big deal), have been able to get it working on mobile touch scroll (kind of a big deal) but if the user lifts the finger off and the momentum scrolling takes over then the events don't fire until the momentum/scrolling stops.

Does anyone know how to make scroll events trigger during this momentum scroll?

This is what I did to make it work with touch scroll:

```
var stickyElementPosition = $('#thing-to-be-sticky').offset().top;

$(window).on("touchmove",function(){
    var scrollPosition = $('body').scrollTop();
    console.log(scrollPosition);

    if(scrollPosition >= stickyElementPosition){
        $('#thing-to-be-sticky').addClass('stuck');
    }
    else{
        $('#thing-to-be-sticky').removeClass('stuck');
    }

});
```

I made a JS fiddle but am not sure how to use it on a touch device. it just tries to scroll the entire page rather than the iframe/result.

[link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtree5757/NKxpw/4/)